# Android(Kotlin) app run perfect on Android 6 but make devices with Android 10 crashes

Tags: android, kotlin, crash

I found this really bizarre. I built this app using firebase on Kotlin. The app runs well on both Android 6 and 10. But after some time like 1 - 2 hours. The devices with Android 10 will get stuck on black screen and all buttons will be unresponsive. To recover, it need to be hard reset then it will all work again. Connected to Android studio show no error on log. This is my manifest file.

UPDATE: now it is working well with android 10 Telcast tablet device after cleaning my codes but problem still persist with Samsung Tab A (also Android 10). I'm pulling my hair :C

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.impressed_1_0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <activity android:name=".payment"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".choices" />
    <activity android:name=".congrats" />
    <activity android:name=".numpad_dialog" />
    <activity android:name=".biz_redeem" />
    <activity android:name=".customer_redeem" />
    <activity android:name=".sel_log_dialog" />
    <activity android:name=".dashboard" />
    <activity android:name=".launcher_land" />
    <activity
        android:name=".gravity_test"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".biz_dashboard"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".biz_auth"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".launcher"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

        <!-- launch code -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- launch code ends -->

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".customer" />
</application>
```

Comment: This is probably an ANR . Your main thread is not responding . You need to investigate the ANR . There is a library ANR watch-dog which you can use to trace the ANR.

Comment: Yes probably an ANR.. between Android 6 and 10, there are a lot of updating in the SDK. You need to check if you are using, Service, WorkManager .. there some limit from Android 8 ..

Answer (score 1):

OMG after 2 wks of searching and troubleshooting. Here are what steps I did throughout.

1. download platform tools. --> accessing ANR using adb pull (failed)--> get ANR via adb bugreport command then ANR file found under FS/Data/anr
2. reading through ANR files --> multiple records show inconsistent errors across 3 devices each time the crash happens --> no progress done here.
3. finally syncing the gradle fixed everything. ---> damn!! phewwwww